# How select specific custom attribute in an select option field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fixing a horrendous bug in an old web application. For some datasets, the values in an option/select list are unfortunately not unique. But luckily, the custom attribute `test` is unique.

So I have the following HTML structure:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1" test="A">fooA</option>
    <option value="2" test="B">fooB</option>
    <option value="2" test="C">fooC</option>
    <option value="2" test="D">fooD</option>
    <option value="2" test="E">fooE</option>
</select>
```

So I wonder how could set `C` from the custom attribute `test` with the help of Jquery or vanilla JS in the select/dropdown field? The `.attr()` property only changes the properties of the custom attribute `test`, which I not want. I want to set `fooC` in the select field.

**JSFiddle link to try:** http://jsfiddle.net/rnnfk/120/

Comment: If you want to display the test attribute text as the option without showing duplicate values..then try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/rnnfk/123/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute selector to get the option with attribute test with specific value.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/fepinovaqi/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```
$('#dropdown option[test=C]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: I decided to choose your answer as the right one, because you was the earlierst and you included the right version of jQuery in your demo. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First you need to select the attribute with the help of [css attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) then add `selected` attribute  using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Try this technique. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnfk/122/)

```
$('#dropdown option[test=C]').attr( "selected","selected");
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. Unfortunately, Adil was earlier. I upvoted your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just add following code in jquery :-

```
$("#dropdown [test='C']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

It may help you.